# Are vignettes build in a fresh R session when building a package?

Tags: r, r-package

I have read Hadley [guide to vignettes](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/vignettes.html) and I can't find any information about this. How are the vignettes build?
My problem is that it seems that they are build with the suggested packages attached and loaded.

As far as I could test, if I knit it on the console in Rstudio it uses the same environment as the console.

I digged into `devtools::build_vignettes` but it seems to depend on `tools::buildVignettes` which I can't understand and seems like the default used when building a package with `R CMD build`.

This is related to my efforts to solve [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49002455/2886003)

Comment: It depends a bit on the vignette builder selected (usually knitr these days), but yes. It's essentially the same as knitting an RMarkdown document; if you don't put in your `library` calls, it's going to record a bunch of errors.

Comment: Yes, I am using knitr in my packages, and I put my library calls in my vignette code, but that's not the point of the questions

Comment: Yes, when you `knit` on the console, it knits in your current environment by default. If you want `knit` in the console to use a new environment, you can give it `envir = new.env()` - see `?knit` for more details. If you use the `knit` button in the RStudio GUI, it actually calls `rmarkdown::render` and executes in a separate environment. You can find a couple questions related to that on this site if you search.

Comment: My question is about how are knit the vignettes when building a package. Perhaps I need to clarify further the question. What made you think I was interested in knit evaluation? Perhaps your comment is related to the other linked question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When building the package the environment for all the vignettes is shared. So if vignette V1 loads package A, B and C, it will be already loaded for vignette V2 if V2 is build before V1.

That was what I learn from Martin Morgan at Bioconductor [mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/bioc-devel/2018-February/012883.html). I couldn't find any other document explaining it.